# whats the most efficient way to close close gaps?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Hello, so sometimes these gaps occur which you notice way later on.. whats the most efficient way to close these. Cant you just select the edges and make the close with a shortcut?

Best G

Comment: Pressing A, M, B

Answer (score 1):

Greetings George and welcome!

There are a couple of different methods that come to mind to fill the gap you have pictured there.

1. Hit F on the keyboard with both edges you have selected there and it "fill" the gap.  Take note this will leave you with an extra edge you will probably want to dissolve so that all four edges are properly connected.
2. Delete the face and with the open space and select any one of the surrounding edges and hit the F key which will create a face that will fill the void and should be connected properly to all 4 of the surrounding edges.
3. In Vertex mode try the M key which will merge by distance.  You may need to adjust the merge distance and will want to pay attention to where the final verts ended up but could also be a solution.  I prefer the option to join at first/last when using the merge function.
4. And finally something I only recently became aware of is the F2 addon.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImSNOuvkKsw
   The video is a bit older but the way it works is still the same.  I found it very informative.  I hope it helps you as well.

Give the above methods a spin and see which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

as Jason wrote this is the merge solution (using the "merge at cursor")

[image]